# Validate with ZOD

Tags: javascript, validation, typeorm, zod

I'm trying to use zod validator, with typeorm.
I saw few tutorials how to use zod. and i write little code but, it does not work it's saying "message": "payloadSchema.safeParse is not a function".
am trying to validate product store method.

```
export const createProduct = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  try {
    const payloadSchema = {
      body: z.object({
        price: z.number({
          required_error: "price is required",
        }),
        image: z.string({
          required_error: "image is required",
        }),
        translations: z.object({
          ge: z.object({
            title: z.string({
              required_error: "title is required",
            }),
            description: z.string({
              required_error: "description is required",
            }),
          }),
          en: z.object({
            title: z.string({
              required_error: "title is required",
            }),
            description: z.string({
              required_error: "description is required",
            }),
          }),
        }),
      }),
    };

    type Payload = z.infer<typeof payloadSchema>;

    const parsedData = payloadSchema.safeParse(req.body);

    if (!parsedData.success) {
      res.status(400).send({
        error: parsedData.error,
      });
      return;
    }

    const { image, price, translations } = req.body;
    const product = new Product();
    product.image = parsedData.image;
    product.price = parsedData.price;
    product.translations = parsedData.translations;
    await product.save();

    return res.json(product);
  } catch (e) {
    if (e instanceof Error) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        message: e.message,
      });
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Try declaring `payloadSchema` as a zod object: `const payloadSchema = z.object({ body: { //... }  })`. The way you declared `payloadSchema` makes it a plain JS object and as such it does not have the `safeParse` method.

Answer (score 1):

In the `payloadSchema` the `body` field should be z.object. Since you put the `req.body` to the payloadSchema.safeParse(req.body), the body field can be removed from the `payloadSchema`:

```
  const payloadSchema = z.object({
      price: z.number({
        required_error: "price bitch!",
      }),
      image: z.string({
        required_error: "image required",
      }),
      translations: z.object({
        ge: z.object({
          title: z.string({
            required_error: "title is required",
          }),
          description: z.string({
            required_error: "description is required",
          }),
        }),
        en: z.object({
          title: z.string({
            required_error: "title is required",
          }),
          description: z.string({
            required_error: "description is required",
          }),
        }),
      }),
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for response. i have one problem, am searching like 3 hours... can't find how to validate image? i need to validate image it must be max 3mb. jpg, png, gif. do u know how to validate image like this?